# Do I need to hunt sustainably in Dawn of Man?

Tags: dawn-of-man

In real life, if you over-harvest a species, you decrease its rate of regeneration, or even drive it towards extinction.  So, for sustainable harvesting, you must limit the numbers you harvest.  Similarly, when you want a wild population to be sustainable, you will harvest more males than females, since females are more critical to generating the next generation than are males.

When my villagers harvests wild animals in Dawn of Man, does the rate of harvesting, or the ratio of males to females harvested, affect the regeneration of the species?  Do my villagers need to practice sustainable hunting, or can they just harvest whatever they want without causing the species to crash?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to hunt responsibly.  According to [the FAQ](https://madrugaworks.com/dawnofman/faq.php):

> Can you drive a species extinct by hunting them?
>
> No. Every spring new animals will migrate back to the map. Some species will however will go extinct when you reach certain eras, and new ones will appear.

So you get a new batch of animals every spring, no matter what hunting you did in the year prior.